# How do I push the text when I am hovering over an image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have made a simple transition to scale the image, but when the image is scaled the text goes below the picture. How can the image push the text down when I hover over the image?

```css
.item img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.item img:hover,
.item img:active {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="container item">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-300-300-8.jpg">
  </a>
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you paste some code to give your question some context

Comment: @Nsoseka what do mean by "some good"?

Comment: my bad corrected the comment

Comment: @Nsoseka the code is simple: 

The HTML:

    <div class="container item">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="../A1t8xCe9jwL._SL1500_.jpg">
      </a>
      <div class="text-center">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

and CSS: 

#poster-carousel .item img:hover,
#poster-carousel .item img:active{
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

And I have added an ease transition, that's it, I just need the picture to push the text down. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ERLOIBRI I added your code to the question. If it is not correct, please edit it.

Comment: @azeós Thanks, that's exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply just add `margin-bottom` when the hover takes place. This way, when the user hovers over the image, a margin-bottom will take place which will push the text below.

Try this:

```css
.item img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.item img:hover,
.item img:active {
  transform: scale(1.25);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container item">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-300-300-8.jpg"></a>
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the exact thing I needed, and works perfect.

Comment: Glad it helped you Erlo Ibri :)

Comment: The margin value will need to be adjusted for each image size. It's not a perfect solution.

Comment: @azeós I needed it for a card carousel, and made the images same size and everything, so it works perfect for me.

Comment: @Gosi Thus answer helped me and I marked it as correct. What Do You Mean???

Answer (score 1):

Please edit the CSS as given below -

```
#poster-carousel .item img:hover, 
#poster-carousel .item img:active{ transform: scale(1.25); position: absolute;}
```

The picture resize will push the text below instead of covering it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work, it just made the image become even bigger and take another direction to scale, and cover both texts now. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I tried a more *generic* solution.

The problem with `scale` seems to be that it doesn't *re renders* other objects position. But if you change the actual *width* and *height*, it works.

But that adds another problem, you need to add in your CSS the initial width and height for the *transition* to work.

What I did was use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). You need to specify the dimensions of each image, but that makes the CSS reusable, it will work with variable image dimensions.

But if all your images have the same dimensions, you could just add those values directly to the CSS file and avoid using CSS variables.

With [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) I multiplied the initial width by 1.25 (which is the same as 25%).

**Edit: removed height because it's not necessary**

View the examples in full page.

```css
.item img {
  width: var(--w); /* 320px */
  height: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.item img:hover,
.item img:active {
  width: calc(var(--w) * 1.25); /* calc(320px * 1.25) */
}
```

```html
<div class="container item">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-320-240-8.jpg" style="--w:320px">
  </a>
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container item">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" style="--w:640px">
  </a>
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Responsive example:

```css
.item img {
  width: var(--w); /* 320px */
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.item img:hover,
.item img:active {
  width: calc(var(--w) * 1.25); /* calc(320px * 1.25) */
  max-width: 125%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container item">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-320-240-8.jpg" style="--w:320px">
  </a>
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container item">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" style="--w:640px">
  </a>
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So how exactly is this a perfect solution? Images of other sizes will also push the text down according to its height. How is this generic? This solution is only a hassle and adds unnecessary css codes. To make it a perfect solution, html structure has to change where the div is in a container, but that is not the OPs requirement.

Comment: @Gosi I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. I think what OP needs is to maintain the *original* distance between the text and the image while this one grows. If I change the image dimension through *width* and *height*, then that distance will remain the same. Now, if the images have different dimensions, I need to specify different values in the CSS, therefore the use of variables ([e.g.](https://jsfiddle.net/azeos/y14kbzq0/)). You will have the same problem using margin, different dimensions will need different margins ([e.g.](https://jsfiddle.net/azeos/vpkwdsuo/)).

Comment: It's not perfect, but with one CSS I can solve different image dimensions, that's what I mean with *generic*.

Comment: But that's not what the OP wants. He clearly mentioned in his question `How can the image push the text down when I hover over the image?`

Comment: So he wants the text to be pushed down, not maintain the original distance between the text and image.

Comment: @Gosi you could be right, I'm not sure. Looking at his example I see an image scaling up and covering the text. What I understand is that he doesn't want the image to cover the text, that's what -I assume- he means with *push*. Did you see my examples?